# How can I set the direction of my <th> 's children like flex-direction does but without using flex?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a table and in that table I have tr and th.
Due to the incompatibility of IE 11 I'm forced to not to use display: flex in my css.
So, I have a select and a div inside my th like this:

```
<th>
    <select id='gerenciasSelectorAsignarFirmantes' class='selectConInfo'>
    </select>
    <div id='tooltipGerenciaSelectedFirmantes'>
        <span class='demo-icon iconAzulOscuro ititle='Información de la gerencia'></span>
    </div>
</th>
```

The problem is that the div appears below the select and I want those in line instead of vertically like if I would apply flex-direction: row.

There is a way to do it without use flex and without use another table inside? just applying some attribute to th? like vertical direction or something?

Comment: Give `display: inline;` a try

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Wait, I applied display: inline to the child and it worked! I was applying it to the th instead. Thank you.

Comment: try this:  "display:inline-block" and "vertical-align: middle".

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I could apply display: 'inline' to th children and it is working fine. Thank you.